# Assert validation errors on Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Hi I'm trying to create a test for a laravel controller not dependent on the view. I have the following method in my controller class:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'login'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);
    //TODO: Store to database
    return redirect('usuario/nuevo');
}
```

And I found the following code to test whether the request had any errors:

```
public function testStore()
{
    $response=$this->call('GET','usuario.store');
    $this->assertSessionHasErrors();
}
```

As it is this test should pass since I'm sending a request without the required field filled out however PhpUnit returns the following message:

```
Session missing key: errors
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

The only way I can make it work is to try to "see" the error message on the response page by making the test like:

```
public function testStore()
{
    $this->visit('/usuario/nuevo')
        ->press('Crear')
        ->see('Whoops');
}
```

This doesn't work for me for two reasons: 1)The test depends on the view to "press" the button and send the request(I wish to test this in a different test and keep this one strictly for the controller) and 2)The test depends on the 'Whoops' string to be present which is obviously bad practice.

I have found several answers claiming that the fist test code should work, but it simply doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with session start and send empty parameters

```
       $this->startSession();
       $this->call('GET','usuario.store', array(
        'name' => '',
        'login' => '',
        'password' => ''
    ));
    $errors = session('errors');
    $this->assertSessionHasErrors();
    $this->assertEquals($errors->get('name')[0],""your custom error message);// only for checking exact message
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are not testing what you think you are testing.

To execute the controller's store() you should use a POST method and not GET unless your routes are really weird.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now, however I've changed the request call to POST and still get the same result, my routes are setup with Laravel's resource method like:

Route::resource('usuario','Usuarios\UsuariosController');